# Getting FQTV DATA EXISTS FOR THIS PASSENGER in TravelItineraryModifyInfoRQ

Tags: sabre

request-

```
 <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:TravelItineraryModifyInfoRQ   Version="2.1.1">  
       <ns:CustomerInfo>
       <ns:CustLoyalty  MembershipID="520000001221" NameNumber="02.01" 
             ProgramID="EY" RPH="1"  />
       </ns:CustomerInfo>
      </ns:TravelItineraryModifyInfoRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

response-

```
 <soap-env:Body>
             <TravelItineraryModifyInfoRS Version="2.1.1" 
    xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
         <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-04-20T13:13:39- 
             05:00">
               <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                  <stl:Message>.EY/EY FQTV DATA EXISTS FOR THIS PASSENGER.SEE 
                     ITEM  02</stl:Message>
                  <stl:Message>.ENTRY NOT PROCESSED BEGINNING WITH</stl:Message>
                  <stl:Message>FF1¤EY100014486283-02.01</stl:Message>
                  <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
               </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
         </stl:ApplicationResults>
      </TravelItineraryModifyInfoRS>
   </soap-env:Body>
```

Is modification not allowed on membership id.
http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/TravelItineraryAddInfoLLSRQ_v2.2.0_Sample_Payloads.xml
Seems it can  be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the FF data for passenger 02.01 is stored in RPH2, and you're attempting to modify 1, while the passenger's data is still in RPH2.

Try modifying the request to RPH 2:

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <ns:TravelItineraryModifyInfoRQ   Version="2.1.1">  
       <ns:CustomerInfo>
       <ns:CustLoyalty  MembershipID="520000001221" NameNumber="02.01" 
             ProgramID="EY" RPH="2"  />
       </ns:CustomerInfo>
      </ns:TravelItineraryModifyInfoRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
```